# Safari Extension: Refresh Popover on Window or Tab change

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

**The Story**

I am developing a Safari Extension with a popover. No-matter how many tabs or windows I have open, **only the first one that was loaded** dispatches messages to Global.html

I have tried `window.onfocus`, `document.addEventListener("visibilitychange")`, `safari.self.addEventListener("activate")` on the Injected.js.

Windows/Tabs are responding to the above listeners, but only the first-loaded-tab will dispatch a message.

**Goal**

1. User changes tab or window
2. Target Page's Injected.js listens it is activated,
3. Target Page's Injected.js dispatches message to Global.html
4. Global.html receives message
5. Global.html re-renders the Popover.html

Thanks everybody in advance.

Any idea is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

The problem was hiding inside `global.html`

I had declared: `safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false);`
for listening to messages.

The problem with the above is that `activeBrowserWindow.activeTab` was linked to the first page that was loaded.

**Solution** 
`safari.application.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false)`